# @NamedQuery adding CROSS JOIN syntax to SQL and its failing in MySQL

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to set up a NamedEntity Graph in Spring JPA. It was working until I tried to join to a second entity. It's now failing because of a MySQL syntax exception.

The query being output to Hibernate contains a `CROSS JOIN` syntax. For brevity the join looks like this on the output:

```
FROM layouts layout0_
LEFT OUTER JOIN layouts_layout_positions layoutposi1_ ON layout0_.id=layoutposi1_.layouts_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN layout_positions layoutposi2_ ON layoutposi1_.layoutPositions_id=layoutposi2_.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN layout_widgets layoutwidg3_ ON layoutposi2_.defaultWidget_id=layoutwidg3_.id
CROSS JOIN
LEFT OUTER JOIN system_users systemuser4_ ON layout0_.lastUpdateUser_id=systemuser4_.id
WHERE layout0_.id=?
```

I've isolated it directly on the terminal and if I remove that CROSS JOIN statement the query passes.

The query hint:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "graph.layouts.and.positions",
    attributeNodes = {
            @NamedAttributeNode(value = "layoutPositions", subgraph="layoutPositions"),
            @NamedAttributeNode(value="lastUpdateUser")
    },
    subgraphs =
            @NamedSubgraph(name = "layoutPositions", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("defaultWidget")))
```

And my JPA properties, I'm using Hibernate 4 on Spring Data/JPA:

```
HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
factory.setPackagesToScan("com.ideafactory.mvc");


Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","update");
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
jpaProperties.put("hibernat.format_sql", true);
jpaProperties.put("jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes", true);
```

Is there perhaps a dialect setting or something I'm missing?

---

Also I just tried removing the subgraph in the entity graph, and it generates correct SQL. I'm suspecting this is a Hibernate bug....

============================ Edited Here ==============
This problem is very strange indeed. It only occurs on the `lastUpdatedUser` field. In the same base class I have `createdUser` which is the same one to one relationship to SystemUser table. If I change the named attribute node to `createdUser` instead, the query works fine.... I'll post the base class here because I'm obviously missing something with the `lastUpdatedUser` field, maybe someone else can see what the issue is?

```
package com.ideafactory.mvc.systemusers.common.utils;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.ideafactory.mvc.general.forms.DateConstants;
import com.ideafactory.mvc.systemusers.common.model.SystemUser;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Auditable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * This is a new base class for auditing entities.
 */
@MappedSuperclass
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@EntityListeners({AuditingEntityListener.class})
public class AbstractAuditableEntity extends AbstractPersistable<Long> implements Auditable<SystemUser, Long> {

    @Column(length = 30)
    private String externalIdentifier;

    @Basic
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat(pattern = DateConstants.DEFAULT_TIME_FORMAT)
    private DateTime lastUpdated;

    @Basic
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat(pattern = DateConstants.DEFAULT_TIME_FORMAT)
    private DateTime created;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private SystemUser lastUpdateUser;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private SystemUser createUser;

    /**
     * Gets created by audit user.
     */
    @Override
    public SystemUser getCreatedBy() {
        return createUser;
    }

    /**
     * Sets created by audit user.
     */
    @Override

    public void setCreatedBy(SystemUser createdBy) {
        this.createUser = createdBy;
    }

    /**
     * Gets create audit date.
     */
    public DateTime getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    /**
     * Sets create audit date.
     */
    public void setCreated(DateTime creationDate) {
        this.created = creationDate;
    }

    /**
     * Gets last modified by audit user.
     */
    public SystemUser getLastUpdateUser() {
        return lastUpdateUser;
    }

    /**
     * Sets last modified by audit user.
     */
    public void setLastUpdateUser(SystemUser lastUpdateUser) {
        this.lastUpdateUser = lastUpdateUser;
    }


    public SystemUser getCreateUser() {
        return createUser;
    }

    public void setCreateUser(SystemUser createUser) {
        this.createUser = createUser;
    }

    /**
     * Gets last modified audit date.
     */
    public DateTime getLastUpdated() {
        return lastUpdated;
    }

    /**
     * Sets last modified audit date.
     */
    public void setLastUpdated(DateTime lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastUpdated = lastModifiedDate;
    }

    @Override
    public DateTime getCreatedDate() {
        return lastUpdated;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCreatedDate(DateTime dateTime) {
        setCreated(dateTime);

    }

    @Override
    public SystemUser getLastModifiedBy() {
        return lastUpdateUser;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLastModifiedBy(SystemUser systemUser) {
        lastUpdateUser = systemUser;

    }

    @Override
    public DateTime getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastUpdated;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLastModifiedDate(DateTime dateTime) {
        lastUpdated = dateTime;

    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public boolean isNew(){
        return super.isNew();
    }

    public String getExternalIdentifier() {
        return externalIdentifier;
    }

    public void setExternalIdentifier(String externalIdentifier) {
        this.externalIdentifier = externalIdentifier;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        super.setId(id);
    }

    public Long getId()
    {
        return super.getId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue too.  Perhaps it is a bug (or unsupported feature) in Hibernate 4.x.  In my case, I solve this by changing https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/4.3/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/hql/internal/ast/SqlGenerator.java#L390 into:

```
if (right.isEntity() && (right.getType() != SqlTokenTypes.JOIN_FRAGMENT)) {
   writeCrossJoinSeparator();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think I can change the core hibernate code. I hit this again using an entitygraph. I think I'm just going to declare it failed, and switch to Fetch Joins which seem to be doing what I need...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the following hibernate bug (still open):

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9392

Comment: It does look like it, in the original query no, but in the comments in the bottom it mentions the cross join. Strange they wouldn't close this one, I mean I really didn't have to do anything sophisticated to hit this issue...